# Lookaround regex and character consumption

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, raku, rakudo

Based on the documentation for Raku's [lookaround assertions](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Lookaround_assertions), I read the regex `/ <?[abc]> <alpha> /` as saying "starting from the left, match but do not not consume one character that is `a`, `b`, or `c` and, once you have found a match, match and consume one alphabetic character."

Thus, this output makes sense:

```
'abc' ~~ / <?[abc]> <alpha> /     # OUTPUT: «｢a｣␤ alpha => ｢a｣»
```

Even though that regex has two one-character terms, one of them does not capture so our total capture is only one character long.

But next expression confuses me:

```
'abc' ~~ / <?[abc\s]> <alpha> /     # OUTPUT: «｢ab｣␤ alpha => ｢b｣»
```

Now, our total capture is two characters long, and one of those isn't captured by `<alpha>`.  So is the lookaround capturing something after all?  Or am I misunderstanding something else about how the lookaround works?

Comment: At first glance, that looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: What does it mean that your first example with a *negative lookaround* gives `Nil` return, i.e. `'abc' ~~ / <![abc]> <alpha> /;  #OUTPUT: 
Nil`, however, your second example with a _negative lookaround_ gives the same result as a _positive lookaround_: `'abc' ~~ / <![abc\s]> <alpha> /; # OUTPUT: «｢ab｣␤ alpha => ｢b｣»` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<?[ ]>` and `<![ ]>` does not seem to support some backslashed character classes. `\n`, `\s`, `\d` and `\w` show similar results.

`<?[abc\s]>` behaves the same as `<[abc\s]>` when `\n`, `\s`, `\d` or `\w` is added.

`\t`, `\h`, `\v`, `\c[NAME]` and `\x61` seem to work as normal.

Comment: Do you mean to say, "`<?[abc]>` behaves the same whether-or-not `\n`, `\s`, `\d` or `\w` are added." ?

Comment: @jubilatious1 No. Without `\n`, `\s`, `\d` or `\d`, it works as it is supposed to. When you add `\n`, `\s`, `\d` or `\w`, it turns into `<[...]>`.